# How to remove my application's appindicator programmatically?

Tags: indicator, application-development

I know how to add an appindicator menu from my application, but I can't seem to find how to remove it but still keep my program running in the background.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Take a look at the code for [emesene](https://github.com/emesene/emesene/). I'm not sure how they get it done as I haven't seen this part of the code myself, but emesene has an optional application indicator.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found out that you can hide an indicator by calling

```
indicator.set_status(appindicator.STATUS_PASSIVE)
```

Which was all I needed.

Comment: Here's a link to some half-decent AppIndicator docs: http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/ubuntu-11.04/libappindicator/libappindicator-app-indicator.html